# GCC and make: Undefined symbols "_main" referenced from crt1.10.6.o

Tags: gcc

How can I compile both a header and a `*.mm` file together to make an executable from the command line with `make`?

This is my `makefile`

```
CC=gcc

FRAMEWORKS:= -framework Foundation
LIBRARIES:= -lobjc

SOURCE=myheader.h

LDFLAGS=$(LIBRARIES) $(FRAMEWORKS)
OUT=-o execName

all:
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OUT)
```

When I run `make` I get this output:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The only answer to every other post about this problem is that the code doesn't contain a `main()` method. However I *do* have a main method.

My header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//declarations for an enum and methods here

int main(int argc, char * argv[]);
```

My `*.mm` file:

```
#include <myheader.h>

//methods and variable declarations and definitions here

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    //code here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no reference to your .mm file anywhere in your makefile, so it is not getting compiled.

Comment: Do I replace `myheader.h` with `myfile.mm`? Do I separate them with a comma? I've never used `make` before.

Comment: I've posted an answer with a fixed version of your makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fixed version of your makefile:

```
# makefile

CC = gcc

CFLAGS = -Wall
FRAMEWORKS = -framework Foundation
LIBRARIES = -lobjc

SOURCES = myfile.mm

LDFLAGS = $(LIBRARIES) $(FRAMEWORKS)

execName: $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Comment: I get a lot of errors about Obj-C classes not being "declared in this scope" and a lot of errors about the * that precedes Obj-C pointers. Where can I post the output for analysis?

Comment: You would need to post a new question, with relevant source code and error messages, as these are compilation errors and probably not related to your makefile.

Comment: I'd like to point out that if I move the important parts of the header file to the source file I get different warnings (more than just one but they are all similar):
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLError.h:62: error: ‘kCFURLErrorCancelled’ was not declared in this scope`